# Javascript 1.1 / HTML 3.0 Audio Player

Tags: javascript, html, retro-computing

I'm building a Dreamcast website, and the machine doesn't recognise any code newer than HTML 3.0 and Javascript 1.1. I want to have an audio player on the site, preferably one that can stream from an online radio station, but all the Flash based players are failing and I'm struggling to find information that isn't HTML5 or CSS.

Does anyone know how to place a legacy player/streamer into a site that is compatible with radio streaming links (Anything that uses IP and Port info for listening to streams is failing due to the death of Flash).

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know enough about Dreamcast to say for sure, but you just may not be able to do this, period. There's a reason we didn't have streaming audio in 1998.

Comment: That's definitely possible. Looking further the DC uses Windows CE for the browsers, which means it utilises a slightly simplified Internet Explorer 5/6 code, does that help in finding a solution (or writing a solution off if it wasn't plausible in the browser)?

Comment: Actually, it really indicates that it would be even harder to do, assuming that this is possible in the first place.